# Problems signing into pokemon account

Tags: pokemon-go

I set up a pokemon go account last week but used an email address which I didn't realise I've no longer got access to.  Now if I log in it asks me to verify my account which I can't do.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

The fastest way to resolve your problem is to create another Pokemon account with an email address you have access.
If you can't or don't want, you can try to use the "password lost" feature of your email provider.